# How to iterate among branches in git using BASH?

Tags: bash, git, git-branch

I am pretty new in Bash. On git, I have branches named like following (YYcwXX):

- version/21cw22
- version/21cw23
- version/21cw24
- version/20cw35
- master

I want to iterate among them and store the one which has the latest current week number - e.g 21cw24 in a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `git branch` to list the relevant branches, sort them, and use `tail` to take the last. Then, I'd just trim away whitespaces and store in a variable:

```sh
export MY_BRANCH=`git branch | grep 'version/' | sort | tail -1 | tr -d ' '`
```